# CSS attribute selector for class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

All. I have some trouble with the css selector in my code . Please review the below code .

Say you have the html structure like below.

```
<div id="currentTmpContainer" class="layoutcontainer container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul id="sortable1" class="sortableLayoutSection">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul id="sortable3" class="sortableLayoutSection">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <ul id="sortable3" class="sortableLayoutSection">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to select the `div` with the class name begin with "span".
So I wrote the selector(`Attribute selectors`) below, but it doesn't work.

```
.layoutcontainer div[class^=”span”]
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some weird slanty quotes going on here.  Use normal ASCII quotes, `"`

```
.layoutcontainer div[class^="span"]
{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/YpmUy/ -- seems to work just fine